# How is this step performed in Deutsch's algorithm?

Tags: linear-algebra, deutsch-jozsa-algorithm

I am reading *Quantum Computing for Computer Scientists*.
Given the circuit for Deutsch's algorithm:

[image: Quantum circuit for Deutsch's algorithm]

Denoting $H|0\rangle$ as $|x\rangle$, the book says that

$|\phi_2\rangle = (-1)^{f(x)}|x\rangle\left\lbrack \frac{|0\rangle - |1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}} \right\rbrack$

and then goes on to explain that because $|x\rangle$ is the superposed state $H|0\rangle$, this is the same as

$|\phi_2\rangle = \left\lbrack\frac{(-1)^{f(0)}|0\rangle + (-1)^{f(1)}|1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}\right\rbrack\left\lbrack \frac{|0\rangle - |1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}} \right\rbrack$

How do they perform this step given that they need to evaluate $f(x)$ but $|x\rangle$ is superposed? I know I could multiply everything out, apply $U_f$ to the basic states, and then rearrange to get the desired form, but is there a simpler way to see that second equation from the first one? I can get the following:

$|\phi_2\rangle = \left\lbrack\frac{(-1)^{f(x)}|0\rangle + (-1)^{f(x)}|1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}\right\rbrack\left\lbrack \frac{|0\rangle - |1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}} \right\rbrack$

but then I am lost. Does it always amount to going to basic states and then returning to a more compact form or can I do something smarter?

Answer (score 0):

The key point here is that the query oracle $U_f$ is a linear transformation.

Linearity means, if $|x\rangle = \alpha|0\rangle+\beta|1\rangle$, then

$$U_f|x\rangle|y\rangle=U_f(\alpha|0\rangle+\beta|1\rangle)|y\rangle=\alpha U_f|0\rangle|y\rangle+\beta U_f|1\rangle|y\rangle\,.\tag{1}$$

---

Now, we have
$$U_f|x\rangle|y\rangle=|x\rangle|y \oplus f(x)\rangle\,,\tag{2}$$

and when $|x\rangle$ is either $|0\rangle$ or $|1\rangle$, and $y=|-\rangle$, we get

$$U_f|x\rangle|-\rangle=(-1)^{f(x)}|x\rangle|-\rangle\,.\tag{3}$$

So,

$$\begin{align}U_f\bigg[\frac{|0\rangle + |1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}\bigg]|-\rangle
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}U_f|0\rangle|-\rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}U_f|1\rangle|-\rangle
\tag{4.1}\\ &= \frac{(-1)^{f(0)}}{\sqrt{2}}|0\rangle|-\rangle + \frac{(-1)^{f(1)}}{\sqrt{2}}|1\rangle|-\rangle
\tag{4.2}\\ &= \bigg[\frac{(-1)^{f(0)}|0\rangle + (-1)^{f(1)}|1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}\bigg]|-\rangle\tag{4.3}\end{align}$$